# Is it beneficial to parallelize variable declaration?

Tags: c, openmp, parallelism-amdahl

I wonder if it is beneficial when writing a parallel program to insert variables declarations into the parallel section? Because the Amdahl's law says that if more portion of the program is parallel it's better but I don't see the point to parallelize variables declaration and return statements, for example, this is the normal parallel code:

```
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    int b[5];

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            b[i] = a;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Will it be beneficial regarding Amdahl's law to write this (so 100% of the program is parallel):

```
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b[5];
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            b[i] = a;
        }

        return 0;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I doubt this would do anything to the performance of the code because the compiler will optimise these instructions.

Comment: These codes are not equivalent: in the first case, `a` and `b` are shared variables (since *shared* is the default behavior for variables), in the second case these are thread-private variables that do not exist beyond the scope of the parallel region. Besides, I would think that having the `return` statement within the parallel region is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

These codes are not equivalent: in the first case, a and b are shared variables (since shared is the default behavior for variables), in the second case these are thread-private variables that do not exist beyond the scope of the parallel region.

Besides, the `return` statement within the parallel region in the second piece of code is illegal and must cause a compilation error.

As seen for instance in this [OpenMP 4.0 reference card](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.0-C.pdf)

> An OpenMP executable directive applies to the succeeding structured
>   block or an OpenMP construct. Each directive starts with #pragma omp.
>   The remainder of the directive follows the conventions of the C and
>   C++ standards for compiler directives. A structured-block is a single
>   statement or a compound statement with a single entry at the top and a
>   single exit at the bottom.

A block that contains the `return` statement is not a structured-block since it does not have a single exit at the bottom (i.e. the closing brace `}` is not the only exit since `return` is another one). It may not legally follow the `#pragma omp parallel` directive.